# If input box have given string then do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to write a script that when my input field has a given value, my script will prompt the user with an alert:
When value of the input field is string: "vuanhtuan" then prompt the user something.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) { 
        alert("your url contains the name franky"); 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

The code above is used for reading from a URL but I have no idea how to change this so that it works with an input field.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We're here to help with existing code. Please post what you have already tried. Thanks.

Comment: What is the hard part? Detecting a change in input? Comparing the value? Prompting?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) {
       alert("your url contains the name franky");
    }
});
</script>
I need a script like this but for input box, the above code is for url, please help me

Comment: Umh ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: `$("#inputid").val()` returns the contents of the input box. What more do you need to know?

Comment: @ĐặngQuốcTrung If you have a input box with ID as `inputid`, the code `$("#inputid").val()`(from @Barmar comment) would return its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an input field like

```
<input type="text" id="someid">
```

Then you can use

```
if ($("#someid").val().indexOf("franky") != -1) {
    alert("your input contains the name franky");
}
```

Comment: it work, thank you so much!